# Is it possible to pair BluetoothDevice programmatically android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Currently Iam using backport.android.bluetooth2.jar file for bluetooth programming with Android 1.5.Whenever device pairing fails it populates alert dialog for passKey and if i give passkey then in my log iam getting below error

```
07-21 12:25:52.419: WARN/BluetoothDeviceService(948): setPin(00:0E:6D:BA:89:F3) called but no native data available, ignoring. Maybe the PasskeyAgent Request was cancelled by the remote device or by bluez.
```

For successfully pair my BT device I always rebooting my tablet and manually pair the device with Settings options.So at last i realised to give this passKey programmatically but i haven't found any method for this.But in google opensource i found one method that is commented with @hide `setPassKey(String Address,int passKey)` in `BluetoothDevice.java` of `backport.android.bluetooth2.jar` .This will n't appear in my jar file.If any way is there for pairing the unbounded device please give reply ASAP?

Comment: Please any one give me response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AndroidBluetoothAPI_0.3.jar file following methods are available i,e: **pair(address)** and **setPin()** for setting the pin programmatically and connecting the BT device.For finding the signal strength method is available in this api.Below is the code project link

http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/downloads/detail?name=AndroidBluetoothAPI_0.3.jar&can=2&q=